# Installation of Django Debug Toolbar: TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: django-debug-toolbar

**Django 1.10**

**django-debug-toolbar==1.5**

I am working on a new project (I've just installed Django). Trying to install Django Debug Toolbar.

Documentation: https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#prerequisites

According to the documentation, this release of the django-debug-toolbar is compatible with Django 1.10.

What have I done wrong?

**settings.py**

```
# { django-debug-toolbar
DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PATCH_SETTINGS = False
INTERNAL_IPS = ['127.0.0.1', ]
if DEBUG:
    MIDDLEWARE += ['debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',]
    INSTALLED_APPS += ['debug_toolbar',]
# } django-debug-toolbar
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include
if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar
    urlpatterns += [
        url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    ]
```

**Traceback**

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f97d6ab9840>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/photoarchive/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/photoarchive/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 142, in inner_run
    handler = self.get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/photoarchive/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/runserver.py", line 27, in get_handler
    handler = super(Command, self).get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/photoarchive/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 64, in get_handler
    return get_internal_wsgi_application()
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/photoarchive/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 49, in get_internal_wsgi_application
    return import_string(app_path)
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/photoarchive/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 20, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/michael/workspace/photoarchive/photoarchive/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/photoarchive/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
    return WSGIHandler()
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/photoarchive/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 153, in __init__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/photoarchive/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 82, in load_middleware
    mw_instance = middleware(handler)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Answer (score 12):

Django 1.10 introduced new style of middleware:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.10/#new-style-middleware

There was [a bug in **django-debug-toolbar**](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar/issues/853) related to that change. The bug [is now fixed](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar/commit/b345cb5f20bb4dea6c918ef05b844670439f4b73) in version 1.6 or later, so just use the [latest version released to PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/django-debug-toolbar/).

---

If you must use versions of django-debug-toolbar older than 1.6 with Django 1.10 or later, you can change MIDDLEWARE to MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES in the Django settings.

Answer (score 3):

I changed MIDDLEWARE to MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES in settings.py.
It's work for me!

Comment: You should really add some explanation as to why this should work 
- in its current form, your answer does not provide any explanation which can help the rest of the community to understand what you did to solve/answer the question. Specifically, you need to explain how these settings make it work.

Comment: If you change MIDDLEWARE to MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES the value of MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES is ignored.

This is the warning i get: WARNINGS:
?: (1_10.W001) The MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES setting is deprecated in Django 1.10 and the MIDDLEWARE setting takes precedence. Since you've set MIDDLEWARE, the value of MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES is ignored.

So that's the reason he can run it...
Official documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.10/#new-style-middleware

Answer (score 1):

Already fixed. There is no need to rename MIDDLEWARE. Just install directly from git:

```
pip install https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar/archive/master.zip
```

And instead of `stable` use the `latest` docs:
http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: As of Sept. 29, when using the recommended [Explicit Setup](http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#explicit-setup), the regular old `pip install` version from PyPI doesn't work. Installing from github as above does.